# Texture Co-ordinate Object Mode is not' working as expected

Tags: shader-nodes, texture-coordinates

I am trying to create some procedural textures.
I have created a 100mm X 100mm plane to try it out
However the object mode seems to be zoomed in. The Geometry and and UV modes are working fine.
Please first two screenshots with object mode.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The *Object* output provides a coordinate system in the local space of the object set in the *Object* field. If the *Object* field is left blank, the coordinates will be provided in the local space of the owning object.

In your case, the object has a scale of 1.0 and a width of 0.1 meter. Since the origin is centered, the *x* component will have a value from -0.05 to 0.05 (left to right). If you want it to go from -0.5 to 0.5, you will need to scale the output by 10 as shown below.

[image: Scaled]

Basically, at a scale of 1.0, every meter in 3D space is converted to one unit in the *Object* coordinate system.

Comment: Really appreciate your clear explanation and the screenshot.  It was driving me nuts for the past few  days... It does seem to work as expected after adding the scale node.


I am still trying to warp my head around about two things:
1. How scaling 10 times actually makes it smaller. 
2. Does this mean that, even if you set your units as MM, Blender still uses meter behind the scene?

Comment: You're welcome! (1) The scaling is done on the values which makes a value of 0.05 become 0.5, for example. This makes the -0.5 to 0.5 range fit the small plane, so in a sense, the value scaling makes the UV space smaller. (2) If I remember correctly, the units are just a visual thing. 1 unit is still 1 meter in Blender. You can verify this by setting the *Unity System* to *None*.

Answer (score 1):

Object coordinate in object mode means that you get the position of a point on the mesh in local space and use it as a coordinate. In your case, if the x-coordinate of the corner is 0.05, you should expect a small cutoff of preview (that looks like in the range -1 ↔ 1).

To test this, I suggest you temporarily disable units in the scene. In this case, I'm assuming the object dimensions will be 0.1, which means your coordinates will be between -0.05 and 0.05, basically a small area in the center of your node preview.

The generated coordinates are usually automatically scaled to fit the object into the 0 ↔ 1 range, so the result will always be about the same

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Mr. A's solution works without disabling the unit, but your reply also helped me to have some better understanding.